# Why isn’t Ubuntu starting up?

Tags: drivers, usb

I already installed Ubuntu in my computer and erased windows 10, but when I turn it on it only takes me to “GNU GRUB” and I do not know what commands I have to type there to start Ubuntu. HELP!

Comment: Just select the entry for Ubuntu and it will boot up .

Answer (score 0):

This is always very scary if you are a new user, but it you keep calm and are willing to do some research, it can often be resolved.

For any more specific advice, you'll need to provide more information, have you done anything to your system recently? how many drives do you have? etc.

When this happened to me, I was able to follow a process [similar to this one](https://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2016/03/booting-gnulinux-manually-with-grub-prompt.html) and it worked fine. I would advise that you read the link, but be careful before executing any commands as your system will be different to the one in the article.

One thing to note is that you can probably access the filesystem by booting from the USB stick you installed it with (or indeed any bootable Linux USB). This will allow you to copy any data from the device that you may need.